# How to setup multiple queues in RabbitMQ and connect using MassTransit 3?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

**Problem**

Using MassTransit I see examples for connecting to a queue like this:

```
var host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/Dev_Queue"), h =>
{
    h.Username("guest");
    h.Password("guest");
});
```

However, when I try this I keep getting the following exception:

{"Connect failed: guest@localhost:5672/Dev_Queue"}

Inner Message:

{"The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Library, code=541, text=\"Unexpected Exception\", classId=0, methodId=0, cause=System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.Frame.ReadFrom(NetworkBinaryReader reader)\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ReadFrame()\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.MainLoopIteration()\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.MainLoop()"}

If I don't specify the queue, then it works fine.

**Full configuration**

This will work because I don't specify the queue, just the url.

```
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
{
    x.AutoDelete = false;
    x.UseJsonSerializer();
    x.UseTransaction();
    x.ExchangeType = "direct";
    x.Durable = true;
    var host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
    {
        h.Username("guest");
        h.Password("guest");
    });
    x.UseRetry(Retry.Immediate(2));
});
```

**Background**

We have two servers we want to run a cluster for high availability. I was able to create the cluster fine and see the queues replicated across each node.

The problem is, these machines have "environments" that are shared. They have to be shared because we do Blue/Green deployments and we don't know what set of servers are in production or not. This is why I want Beta and Production queues, however, in MassTransit I have been unable to successfully point to a specific queue that I want the messages to go into.

Any help or additional insight on this architecture would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MassTransit, the host only specifies the host name and virtual host name. So in your example above, a virtual host named "Dev_Queue" would need to exist. Clearly that isn't your intent.

In your complete example, you need to add receive endpoints for receiving messages.

```
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
{
    x.AutoDelete = false;
    x.UseJsonSerializer();
    x.UseTransaction();
    x.ExchangeType = "direct";
    x.Durable = true;
    var host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
    {
        h.Username("guest");
        h.Password("guest");
    });
    x.UseRetry(Retry.Immediate(2));

    x.ReceiveEndpoint("Dev_Queue", e =>
    {
        e.Consumer(() => new MyConsumer());
    })
});
```

Also, check out the migration documentation from v2:

http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/migrating/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the link, since I am just now dropping into this I wouldn't have thought to read the migration guide. A few things now make more sense. However, since the web application is only the push portion of the equation, this won't solve my problem because from what I understand, now the web application will read messages from the queue. What I am trying to achieve is have the service do the processing to improve site responsiveness.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to not have any messages lost. MassTransit offers interaction with RabbitMQ and gives us a migration route when going to Azure. Do you think I am utilizing this technology properly or should I go direct with RabbitMQ instead?

Comment: You're right on. If you don't receive on the web site don't create any receive endpoints. Create those in your services and send and/or publish your messages from the web site. The queue names are only needed for the receive endpoints if you are publishing messages.

Comment: @Chris i want to make receive endpoint queue as high available, how can i achieve it?
Because when i put the "ha=true" at the end of "ServiceQueueName", it throws exception.

Comment: You can't specify HA from the client with RabbitMQ any longer. The broker itself requires a policy to be created on the server to enable HA.